# My css won't load after i declare it on head of html

Tags: html, css, go

My folder looks like this:

```
root/
-templates/
--css/
---styles.css
--chat.html
-main.go
```

Here was my handler:

```
http.Handle("/", &templateHandler{filename: "login.html"})

http.Handle("/css/", http.StripPrefix("/css", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./templates/css/"))))

http.Handle("/chat", MustAuth(&templateHandler{filename: "chat.html"}))

http.Handle("/login", &templateHandler{filename: "login.html"})

http.Handle("/room", r)
```

At the head of my chat.html, i link my css with code below

```
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="styleshseet" >
```

When I am starting to Listen and Serve it, the CSS won't load.
But when I put style code in my HTML head like below, it works.

```
<style>
 my CSS code
</style>
```

Integrity bootstrap CSS also work properly, and I have tried to put my CSS on raw Github, it also doesn't work,

```
<link href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Triad-0112/Web-ChatProject/master/chat/templates/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/chat/templates/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="./css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

All those three also don't work.
Any idea what did I miss?

Comment: Use absolute paths, e.g. `href="/css/styles.css"`. A relative path in `href` will result in a request sent to a path relative to the current path, i.e. if your browser is on `/` then `href="css/..."` will result in request to `/css/...`, but if your browser is on `/chat` then `href="css/...` will result in a request to `/chat/css/...`, but your Go server is serving the. files from `/css/`, not `/chat/css/`.

Comment: `href="raw.githubusercontent.com/blabal"` - this is not linking to github. You need to add a https:// in front of it, i.e. `href="https://raw.....` . Otherwise it will be just treated as a site-local resource.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich oh yeah my bad I write wrongly for that... but I know what do you mean... It also doesn't work.

Comment: @mkopriva I also have tried giving either a full path or an absolute path. It also doesn't work.

Comment: @PanjiTriWahyudi don't use full path. Always use only the absolute path based on how you have setup your `http.FileServer`. If it is still unable to serve files then you should include more details. For example "It doesn't work" isn't very descriptive. What is the error that you are getting? Open the browser network console and describe what you see there that's relevant to your problem. Or open the browser and manually navigate to `/css/styles.css`, does it load the file? do you get 404? Or some other error?

Comment: If you request it from raw GitHub, the mime type won't be correct. You can check in the network tab.

Comment: myhost/css/styles.css
let say
I put my chat.html, which is the dir structure I already tell on above.
myhost/chat
on my chat.html, I put link CSS to /css/styles.css which was it worked well when I try to access it through myhost/css/styles.css

Comment: @mkopriva I don't know which error I should provide xD... there is no error shown that is related to the problem files. 
I also have tried /css/styles.css, it doesn't work even When I check on a browser with accessing myhost/css/styles.css it shows my CSS code. But when I try to link it on my chat.html, it doesn't load, I have checked sources my css wasn't there, also have checked my console, it doesn't show anything except my extension error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry. It won't load because it loads old CSS from cookies. When I switched to another browser, it worked by using /css/, which I declared on the CSS Fileserver handler. Thanks mkopriva